# Does GRUB completely replace MBR or just the MBR's boot code

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

When we dual boot a computer with windows and linux(latter) then grub is installed over the mbr by default, BUT which approach is followed -

1. The MBR(512 bytes) is completely replaced by the grub. The grub creates its own partition table and uses it. At boot time after BIOS is initialized, GRUB is loaded which further goes to stage 1, 1.5 and 2.

2. Only the boot code of MBR(around 446 bytes) is replaced with GRUB and GRUB uses the partition table of the DEFAULT MBR. 

Kindly help me clarifying things.

Comment: What is "default mbr and its partition table"?

Comment: One that was there before installing linux !!! .

Comment: ...and what happens to the previous (not default!) partition table after more partitions are created/deleted/modified bi the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: That part is simply managed by the grub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corresponding section from the documentation: [10 GRUB image files](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Images)

> `boot.img`
>
> On PC BIOS systems, this image is the first part of GRUB to start. It is written to a master boot record (MBR) or to the boot sector of a partition. **Because a PC boot sector is 512 bytes, the size of this image is exactly 512 bytes.**
>
> The sole function of `boot.img` is to read the first sector of the core image from a local disk and jump to it. Because of the size restriction, `boot.img` cannot understand any file system structure, so `grub-setup` hardcodes the location of the first sector of the core image into `boot.img` when installing GRUB.

You should read the rest of the chapter and also [3.4 BIOS installation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#BIOS-installation).

Both of your assumptions or given options are inaccurate:

- > When we dual boot a computer with windows and linux…

  That is the first wrong assumption. Bare hard drives don't ship with any operating system.
- > The grub creates its own partition table and uses it.

  That would imply loosing information about all previously created partitions, but GRUB is not a partition manager in the first place. **The format of the partition table and partitions themselves have already been configured and created** on a blank drive **at the time GRUB or any other kind of bootloader is invoked in an operating system installation process**. The role of a bootloader package during installation is to detect if it is compatible with the environment and use appropriate mechanisms to deploy itself.
- > GRUB is loaded which further goes to stage 1, 1.5 and 2.

  There are no stages in GRUB 2's design, read the *For GRUB Legacy users* section from the first link above.
- > Only the boot code of MBR(around 446 bytes) is replaced with GRUB and GRUB uses the partition table of the DEFAULT MBR.

  There is no "DEFAULT MBR", only the partition table ***you*** chose to use in previous steps of the installation process and it doesn't have to be a partition table in the legacy MBR format at all. If there is no other mechanism than to read and parse 512 bytes, replace whatever bytes and write 512 bytes back then this will be done and it shouldn't even matter to you since nothing else but what you chose should be performed on the disk and its layout. You may even find that your hard drive writes [whole 4K sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/512e).

N.B.: It's hard to find actual BIOS systems in stores these days. Hardware certification for Windows 8 required manufacturers to ship UEFI systems. Intel and motherboard manufacturers were shipping UEFI systems for a few years at that time, but they had to rely on compatibility to legacy boot mechanisms until Microsoft decided to switch.